# C++ left of getter() must have class/struct/union

Tags: c++, class, oop, pointers, getter

I am trying to do an exercise on class inheritance in C++. The main idea is that I have a point class (defining a point by 2 coordinates) and I have different shapes (such as rectangle, square, triangle ...etc)

My point class has a some getters called getX() and getY(), they both return double values.

In all of my shape classes (rectangle, square, triangle) I have a print method that prints their class members to the console. In that method I need to get the x and y of a an instance of Point. The problem is I get the following compile error when I do so :

```
error C2228: left of '.getX' must have class/struct/union
```

Here are some pastebins with the rest of my code :

Point class header : http://pastebin.com/vA29dTkE

Point class cpp file : http://pastebin.com/E8GKrsHT

Rectangle class header : http://pastebin.com/pXNXX18q

Rectangle class cpp file: http://pastebin.com/R09vgfdb

The issue occurs on lines 18 and 19 in the rectangle class cpp file.
Thanks for any help in advance :)

Comment: pastebin links don't last forever - StackOverflow asks that you post minimal, complete code directly in the question, so it and any answers remain potentially useful to later readers.

Comment: Hello! If I read well, when you use `point origin(double, double);` you create a function named origin, not a point named origin. You must write point `origin;` to create a variable in your poly that is named origin. And then in your constructor, you call the constructor of point on your variable origin. 
Here, when you call `origin.getX();` you call `getX()` on a function and not on a point, so it doesn't work.

Comment: You need to post an [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

```
 point rectangle::origin(double, double);
```

is a function that takes two doubles, therefore you have to call it like:

```
double rectangle::draw()
{
    std::cout << "Rectangle membembers:\n";
    //x = this->origin.getX();
    std::cout << this->width;
    std::cout << this->height;
    std::cout << this->origin(0, 0).getX(); // here
    std::cout << this->origin(0, 0).getY(); // here
}
```

you probably wanted to declare and use it as:

```
class rectangle : polygon
{
private:
    point origin;
};

rectangle::rectangle(double x, double y, double width, double height)
 : origin(x, y) {
    this->width = width;
    this->height= height;
}
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure he doesn't want origin to be a function but a variable of type point. (Where's the point of origin being a function here?)